# Setting formdata Object by using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have my Object state here written in vanilla javascript. and i wanted to convert it into typescript.

**This is the state for formData object.**

```
 const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
     firstName: "",
     lastName: "",  
 });
```

**This is the handleFormChange function.**

```
const handleFormChange = (event) => {
const { name, value } = event.target;
setForm(prevFormData => (
  ...prevFormData,
  [name]:value;
));
```

};

on vanilla js it's working perfectly fine. What could be the type definition for

**[name]:value;**

Comment: Please show what research you've done and what attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Input `OnChange`
> Getting the value from an input `onChange` event is one of the first things people learn when working with HTML. In a Typescript environment, it can be tempting to use any as a type for the `onChange` event. Instead of any , you can `useReact.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>`

```
const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) =>
//That will give you access to all the values included in the input onChange event.
```

> If you are using a text area and need to differentiate the event, you can use this instead:

```
const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also share your `setForm` function here so I can try to answer your question based on that. Actually it would be even better if you could share your code with a CodeSandbox link. Btw this is not Vanilla JS, you use React's `useState`. I would suggest you to check [React TypeScript CheetSheet](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/).

Comment: bro, it's literally on handleFormChange function. Anyway, thank you for the  cheatsheet.